# PostgreSQL 9.6 server process terminated by 0xc0000374

Tags: windows, bash, postgresql, etl, heap-corruption

I have a pretty large project in which I am executing something about 500 queries one after the other and exporting the data and loading it later when process is finished, in another table, all through psql and a bash script on Windows.

PostgreSQL is crashing with this in the logfile:

> LOG: server process (PID 5776) was terminated by exception 0xc0000374
>
> DETAIL: Failed process was running: COPY ( SELECT ...)
>
> HINT: See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.

Unfortunately I don't have much details on the frequency of this. Seems like sometimes happens and sometimes not and it's not clear when it happens. Looks random to me... It's driving me crazy.

Now 0xc0000374 seems to mean [Heap Corruption Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2015/01/30/heap-corruption-exception-0xc0000374/) which is still not so helpful applying it to my context.

How can I understand what's going on better or prevent it? I would be grateful for any feedback!

Comment: Are you using any extensions? Do you have any reason to suspect the hardware, any other instability? If not, please file a bug report. Even better would be to enable minidumps and submit a dumpfile with your bug report.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Windows#Using_crash_dumps_to_debug_random_and_unpredictable_backend_crashes

Comment: I am indeed using some extensions in the process. I am generating a massive string and storing it in a text column quite often. When I reduced size of this string by a bit, the error vanished -- but stil I would prefer if I didn't have to go down this road and I can't understand what possibly could be happpening. I thought text type had a ridiculously large limit?

Comment: ... and those extensions are? `text` has a huge limit, sure, and when it hits it it should not be crashing. So something is wrong. You now need to determine what. Get a stack trace or a minidump to analyse. List the extensions you use. etc.

Comment: I am using PostGIS and gevel. Yes, you're right it is a bit odd so I will submit a dump for analysis. Thanks!